# Charging USB-C PD supported laptop from battery bank

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, usb-c, laptop, usb-pd

Is there a way that I can change my USB-C PD supported laptop with battery bank? I have 3.7V 25000 mAH batteries bank. 5X (3.7V, 5000 mAH) batteries are connected in parallel. What sort of circuit design will work for it? Is it even possible or not? Maybe a boost converter to increase batteries voltage? But still I am in doubt how USB-PD of laptop will respond to it.

Comment: USB PD works through negotiation between the source and sink, so without that nothing will happen. First thing you need to know is what voltage(s) and current(s) the laptop will need in order to charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to implement a Power-Delivery-compliant power source. Then your laptop will negotiate a proper power contract automatically.

To make the device you just need to implement a simple circuit similar to this one:
[image]
This particular circuit comes from [STM](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stusb4710.pdf) portfolio of PD products. This circuit will convert a 20-24V source to variable output, so your laptop can find a matching proper power profile. Your 3.7V battery needs to have an upconverter to 20-24V, or the power-in circuitry (U2) needs to be a variable PDO-controlled upconverter itself.

There are may more producers of similar PD controller chips, TI, Infineon, Analog Devices, Diodes, etc.

A simple upconverter to +5V will not provide your laptop with charging, a 5V-based PD profile usually is not enough to charge a normal laptop.

It is a separate story to integrate an AC-DC charger to your battery pack.

Comment: Your example circuit uses a buck topology, the OP says they have the 3.7V batteries in parallel. You need a boost topology for this task

Comment: @Ferrybig, thanks, my omission. My idea of this answer is to illustrate the gap between "is there a way" and actual implementation of a Typ-C PD charger.